# How to use DATEVALUE with diffent locale setting without changing system settings

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time, text-formatting

I have an Excel column that uses US date format, i.e. `MM/DD/YYYY`, but is a text column. I need to convert it to the date column for which I'd normally use the `DATEVALUE()` function. However, because my language and formatting settings are not US, Excel will show the `#VALUE!` error.

Now I could go and change my system settings, maybe even Excel settings (I think I've seen date and number format settings there) but I'd much rather solve this issue using universal Excel functions only. I.e., I don't want to move to another computer, possibly with other locale settings, and have to worry about this again.

Do I need to do some kind of text parsing?

Comment: Why not reformat the cell to custom `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: The cell if of type "Text" so just giving it a format will not help.

Comment: Giving it custom format using m,d and y will show it as a date instead of text.

Comment: No, it will not. Excel must first store the date as an appropriate "numeric" value but if you throw some text at it, it will not automagically understand that text and convert it to something else. Petr's answer below shows the complexity of the real solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Borek, I believe the following may solve the issue

**=DATE(RIGHT(RefCell,4),LEFT(RefCell,FIND("/",RefCell)-1),MID(RefCell,FIND("/",RefCell)+1,FIND("/",RefCell,FIND("/",RefCell)+1)-FIND("/",RefCell)-1))**

I assumed the delimiter is "/" based on your description and that the year is formatted as YYYY. I hope this does the trick.

Comment: Haven't tested it yet but after some research, a function like this is probably the solution. Thanks.

Comment: DATE function can process text values as the Year/month/day arguments, e.g. `=DATE("2014","10","16")` is a valid formula to give today's date, so the above will work without the `VALUE` functions"

Comment: This solves the particular problem in the OP's question, but not the general problem of the OP's question. My dates are using the names of the months in French, for example, and my system is in English.